# Windows 10 Pro: Prevent it from adding extra displays/monitors

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors

I have an issue where `Windows` seemingly insists on **creating multiple displays/monitors** for me, after which some programs are set to appear on those non-existing displays, so they're not visible. I tried *deleting* them via `Device Manager` which worked temporarily, but after a reboot they were recreated. I only have my laptop display + one external monitor sometimes connected.

I have read a solution for people whose primary graphics card is `Nvidia` - where they can be removed in `Nvidia Control Panel` - and another solution for people who run either `Windows 10 Enterprise` or `Windows 10 Pro For Workstations`, where the displays can be *deleted* in *Settings -> System -> Display* - but neither apply to my case.

Both those solutions are mentioned [here](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/154973-how-remove-display-desktop-windows-10-a.html).

Is there a solution for users who Run Windows 10 Pro/Home and who don't have Nvidia as their primary graphics card?

Screenshot from `Device Manager`:
[image: Screenshot from device manager showing 6 displays]

Comment: What if you locate which monitors are the ones you don't want are, then right-click -> disable?  you don't delete them so windows will not re-add them, but should keep them disabled.

Comment: Good suggestion. I'll try it out and see. They still appear under `Settings -> System -> Display`, but maybe no programs will appear on them. I'll write if it works, then you can make it an answer and I'll mark it as the Answer.

Comment: Good luck. Keep me posted.

Comment: I think it works alright to disable, actually. If you add that as an answer, I will accept it.

The window issue still happens occasionally since I switch between two monitors, and even though I never use both at the same time it still sometimes decides to open the window on the other, turned off one. Temporarily using `extend desktop` rather than "PC Screen Only` or `Second Screen Only" and then dragging the window over is a workaround for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Device manager, you can disable devices you don't want to use. It'll stop them from working or updating drivers etc. Windows won't readd them either.

If for some reason a windows spawn in a virtual place, you can still activate that window from the task bar. When it is active, press <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>⬅</kbd> and <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>➡</kbd> to move the window to the previous and next monitor.

If that for some reason doesn't work, hover the window in the taskbar, wait for the thumbnail to popup and right-click on that. Click Move. If Move is grayed out, click the top one and repeat the steps, now Move is available.

After you clicked move, press any of the arrow keys to snap the window to your mouse cursor. Now move the mouse to where you want the window to appear (don't hold down any mouse buttons). At the desired location, click once with the left mouse button to release.